# How to convert IEnumerable<table> to xml or dataset

Tags: xml, linq, dataset, ienumerable

This is the code:

```
IEnumerable<table> results = db_dane.ExecuteQuery<table>(query);
```

- table - is a database table,
- query - sql query (example: select * from table),
- db_dane - linq datacontext.

How to convert results of this query to xml or dataset?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My best thought is to convert it to a List through ToList(), and then looping through that to convert it to a data table.

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/05/09/Converting-an-object-collection-to-a-DataSet.aspx

Messy, but should work.